# javascript oop. Constructor vs prototyping

Tags: javascript, oop

I can understand what is the difference in creating and object as a constructor and creating an object in a literal notation and when is better to use each definition, but I can not understand the difference between the following two cases:

```
function Obj(){
  this.foo = function(){...}
}


function Obj(){}
Obj.prototype.foo = function(){...}
```

Both are doing the same thing. Both will be instantiated using the same `var objNew = new obj();`

So what is the difference and when to use each concept?

Comment: this question has been answered dozens of time before - try searching.

Comment: Object creation using constructor functions and prototype explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototype` is shared by all instances. Let us compare:

```
function Obj(){
  this.foo = function(){...}
}
var o1 = new Obj();
var o2 = new Obj();
console.log(o1.foo === o2.foo); // false
```

versus

```
function Obj(){}
Obj.prototype.foo = function(){...}
var o1 = new Obj();
var o2 = new Obj();
console.log(o1.foo === o2.foo); // true
```

Using a prototype means declaring the prototype properties and functions once, and everyone shares it. A million objects, one `foo` function.

The "in the constructor" approach creates a local `foo` function to instances every time you run it. A million objects, a million `foo` functions each tied its own object.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is slower because it gets created every time you call the constructor.

Comment: and takes more memory.  However the _advantage_ of a function declared within the constructor is that such a function can access any other "private" variable declared in the lexical scope of `Obj`.  Functions on the prototype can't do that.

Comment: @Alnitak Once you're going to declare private instance specific members in the constructor body you can throw away prototype and have a great head ache trying to clone this object. My advice is because you can't see the future and know how this object is going to change; use `_myprivate` instead.